# Junit create test data schema before Bean initialization

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-batch

I have a spring batch app in which a static database table is loaded at startup using the @PostConstruct method.
My Junit test case intends to test end to end of the Spring batch job.
For this I use h2 database to : create test schema -> insert test data -> run test -> destroy test data through @Before and @After of Junit.

The problem with this setup is , when the queries are fired in the PostConstruct method of the above mentioned bean, the schema is yet to be created.

What would be a better way to write the test?

Comment: Is there any reason for using `@PostConstruct` method to load data? I believe this is the root of your problem. Is the data you are loading in this method only needed for the test? What does your job do?

Comment: Basically it's a reference table containing configurations which is used in the job processing.This data will be accessed in every call to the Processor, per item. Hence instead of hitting db every time I created a singleton bean which will load the data at context startup. The data is used in the main batch processing, not specific to the test. I believe there must be a better way to do this which is easily testable.

Comment: Please share your code to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to [@Sql](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-sql) annotation from spring-test module. It can be use in per-class or per-method manner.:

```
@Sql(scripts = "classpath:/sql/db-schema.sql")
class BatchTest {
    @Sql(scripts = "classpath:/sql/minimal-seed.sql")
    @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD,
        scripts = "classpath:/sql/clean-up.sql")
    void testCase1() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

It will prepare your db schema and data and clean-up everything after test case finished. If you put *@Sql* annotation on top of your class it still will run for each test case so make sure to use *if not exists* statements in your DDL.

Also, see [Integration testing with spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing), [@SqlConfig](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-sqlconfig), [SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.html)

Comment: But this will still be executed post context load right? My problem is during the context load there is a bean which loads data from database. The schema isn't available at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable bean overriding through: `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`, override your post construct service bean in a test config class and make it depended on DataSourceInitializer, which could execute the sql scripts before the service bean is initialized. The test class then can use the config below: `@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)`

TestConfig.class:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("dataSourceInitializer")
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/schema.sql"));
    resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/data.sql"));
    DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(resourceDatabasePopulator, dataSource);
    return dataSourceInitializer;
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("dataSourceInitializer")
public ServiceWithPostConstruct serviceWithPostConstruct (SomeDependencyService someDepencencyService, AnotherService anotherService...) {
    return new serviceWithPostConstruct(someDepencencyService, anotherService...);
}
```